# Send sed output to file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Using `pull_data $a $b | sed 's/, \+\| \+,/g'` which shows the end result on screen but when I try and get this sent to a file for e.g. `pull_data $a $b | sed 's/, \+\| \+,/g' > out` I get errors that out does not exist etc.

What is the correct method to send the output to a file?

Comment: What message exactly are you getting, it's not a permissions message is it? That snytax for IO redirection is fine.

Comment: `sed 's/, \+\| \+,/g'` is **wrong** syntax!! same as: `sed 's/pattern/g`

Comment: Please describe which filter do you wish to applym, and provide the result also.

Comment: I need to remove all spaces after or before a comma, but not spaces between words i.e. the spaces in `,  1  ,` but not the space between the two words in `, Two Words ,`.

Comment: Try `sed 's/ *, */,/g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^ +//; s/ +, +/,/g; s/ +$//' > out
```

remove spaces around commas and also at the beginning and end of the line.